# Does the proving of continuous function redundant?

Tags: probability, analysis

In Kai Lai Chung's A Course in Probability Theory, Page 2:

> For each $x$, $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if$$f(x-)=f(x)=f(x+)$$ To see this ,observe that the continuity of a monotone function $f$ at $x$ is equivalent to the assertion that:$$\lim_{t\uparrow x}f(t) =f(x)=\lim_{t\downarrow x}f(t)$$. and we have $$\lim_{t\uparrow x}f(t)=f(x-)$$ and $$\lim_{t\downarrow x}f(t)=f(x+)$$. and $$f(x-)\leq f(x)\leq f(x+)$$. so we get the conclusion.

I think $f(x-)\leq f(x)\leq f(x+)$ is unnecessary. because if $f$ is a decreasing function. the conclusion is also right. Am I right? This textbook is the third edition. I think it should not have these naive error.

Comment: (Too much) focused on CDFs maybe? Function $f$ does not even have to be monotone. It is enough (and necessary) that the limits $f(x-)$ and $f(x+)$ both exist and coincide with $f(x)$. Existence of the limits is ensured by monotonicity, but it does not imply monotonicity.